# Instantly rebooting from Windows batch file - bypassing system settings change dialog

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wasn't sure whether this was more suited to stackoverflow or serverfault, and posted the same question to serverfault yesterday but received no reply.

I've written a batch file to detect the graphics card type on first boot, silently install its drivers then force a reboot without the user seeing anything.

```
if exist "firstboot.dat" (
start /wait "" "DetectGPU.exe"
del "firstboot.dat"
)

// ...same as below for each possible graphics card in the field
if exist "NVIDIA GeForce 9300 GE.dat" (
Drivers\9300\setup.exe /s /hide_progress /hide_splash
del "NVIDIA GeForce 9300 GE.dat"
shutdown -r -f -t 0
)
```

The card is detected and drivers are installed successfully but before the PC can reboot a System Settings Change dialog appears warning me that Windows has installed a new device and that I must reboot before the settings take effect. This stops the shutdown command from executing. How can I get the PC to reboot before this message appears, or alternatively if I could handle the dialog after the drivers have been installed and choose to reboot there, that would also be great.

Thanks,

Bill.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Win7 or possibly Vista (not sure though) you could try

```
shutdown /r /p /f
```

which is described as shutting down the system with no time out or warning. This combined with `/f` might be enough to get it to shutdown.